# last entire row is not copy to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I try to copy last entire row to another sheet but failed
with this method it"s only copying single cell to all the row

```
Dim lrow As Long

With Worksheets("101")
    lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B" & lrow - 1, "M" & lrow).Copy
    Worksheets("EOM").Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

with this code it gives error

```
Dim shRead As Worksheet
Set shRead = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("101")

Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
lastRow = shRead.Cells(shRead.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = shRead.Cells(lastRow, shRead.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With shRead
    shRead.Range(lastRow, lastCol).Copy_
      Worksheets("EOM").Range(B4, M4)
End With
```

error on

```
shRead.Range(lastRow, lastCol).Copy_
```

Comment: There need to be a space right before the underscore  `.Copy _`. • And `Range(lastRow, lastCol)` should be `Cells(lastRow, lastCol)`. • And `Range(B4, M4)` needs to be `Range("B4", "M4")`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sir thanks for your time but this does not worked already tried.

Answer (score 0):

In place of your code

> ```
> With shRead
>   shRead.Range(lastRow, lastCol).Copy_
>   Worksheets("EOM").Range(B4, M4)
> End With
> ```

You have to put start and end cell for a range

```
With shRead
    .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy Worksheets("EOM").Range("B4")
End With
```

for the destination the cell reference should be in double quotes

**EDIT**

You can use a code similar to the below one; to get data from all worksheets a loop is needed, you can amend the code according to your requirements

```
Dim i As Integer 
i = 4

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(lastRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy Worksheets("EOM").Range("B" & i)
         i = i + 1
     End With
 Next
```

Comment: Sir bundle of Thanks. This amendment worked. Sir can we get from multiple sheets last rows with the help of single command button. Again sir I am greatfull to you Sir

Comment: Dear @UsmanAshfaq I have updated the code to get data from multiple sheets